# How to create a foreign key that references a primary UUID in Knex.js?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, knex.js

The first table gets created fine, but the error happens when it tries to create the second table that references the first.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned, `name` varchar(255) not null, `role` varchar(255) not null, `instagram' at line 1
```

Here is my code:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
 knex.schema
    .createTable("campaigns", (table) => {
      table.uuid("id").primary();
      table.string("name").notNullable();
      table.text("description").notNullable();
      table.string("location").notNullable();
      table.timestamp("created_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now()).notNullable();
    })
    .createTable("user", (table) => {
      table.uuid("id").primary();
      table
        .uuid("campaign_id")
        .unsigned()
        .notNullable()
        .references("id")
        .inTable("campaigns");
      table.string("name").notNullable();
      table.string("role").notNullable();
      table.string("instagram").notNullable();
      table.string("email").notNullable();
      table.bigint("number").notNullable();
    })
```

Comment: I've never used `knex`, but try removing the `unsigned()` from the `user` table for the FK.